# DrJava-2019-220051 using JDK 7.0_7 as my compiler, even though I have JDK8.0_281 installed

Tags: java, java-8, drjava

New to DrJava and downloaded Java 8_281. It's been working all day. Under the compiler in DrJava, it even listed JDK 8 as its compiler. Now, all of a sudden, I open my program and the compiler has switched to JDK 7. It now outputs an error message anytime I try to run my program saying "javacTask: target release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8"

I don't even have JDK 7 installed on my computer. I never had it installed. Plus, it was working fine all day. Then it switches up on me?

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: What output do you get if you type `javac -version`?

Comment: http://drjava.org/docs/userdoc.pdf : _The  preferred  compiler  can  also  be  selected  permanently  by  setting  the  Compiler  Preference  in  theCompiler Options category of the Preferences. DrJava will then choose the selected compiler at startup._